# Input() property undefined for Angular component

Tags: angular

Why is this property undefined?

```
export class DataFormComponent implements OnInit {

  distanceDropdownItems: any[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.distanceDropdownItems = DISTANCE_DROPDOWN_ITEMS;
    console.log('FORMS dropdown items = ', this.distanceDropdownItems); < ---- defined ... [{},{},...]
  }

}
```

Template:

```
<app-input-dropdown [dropdownItems]="distanceDropdownItems"></app-input-dropdown>
```

Child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './input-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-dropdown.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class InputDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() dropdownItems: any[];

  selectedItem: any;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.dropdownItems);  <------- Undefined
    this.selectedItem = this.dropdownItems[0];

    const dropdownButton = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.dropdown-button');
    dropdownButton.classList.remove('dropdown-button');
    dropdownButton.classList.add('dropdown-input-button');

  }

}
```

Comment: post your parent component

Comment: `<app-input-dropdown [dropdownItems]="this.distanceDropdownItems"></app-input-dropdown>`? There is not "items" object in ur component.

Comment: `<app-input-dropdown [dropdownItems]="items"></app-input-dropdown>` prop name should be `[dropdownItems]` not `[items]`

Comment: @el_pup_le , ideally you should hook into your ``ngOnChanges(changes : SimpleChanges)`` and check if you are getting the data in ``changes.dropdownItems`` . you'll have both the previousValue and currentValue

Answer (score 2):

You are using **`items`** instead of **`distanceDropdownItems`** as you showed in the parent component, try channging the variable name as follows,

```
<app-input-dropdown [dropdownItems]="distanceDropdownItems"></app-input-dropdown>
```

Also to avoid undefined or null errors, you could use *ngIf on the parent component to make sure dropdownItems dont throw any errors whenever you initialize the child component

```
<app-input-dropdown *ngIf="distanceDropdownItems"  [dropdownItems]="this.distanceDropdownItems"></app-input-dropdown>
```

**EDIT**

now after the edit it looks like you are using wrong variable on the child component, change your variable as,

```
@Input() items: any[];

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.items);
}
```

**EDIT**

With the latest edit, after you changed your input to **`dropdownItems`**, the template on the parent component should be adjusted as,

```
<app-input-dropdown [dropdownItems]="items"></app-input-dropdown>
```

Comment: the variable name isn't the problem.

Comment: omg, i am sure you are making silly mistake with your code as you did in the quesiton

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you have `items` defined in your dropdown component. In your ngOnInit you should be logging `dropdownItems` instead ro rename the name of input property to `items`. Also in the parent HTML you should be defining the child component with `[dropdownItems]=items`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with the child component and the `@Input()` , i suggest you to do something like this  :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './input-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-dropdown.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class InputDropdownComponent implements OnInit , OnChanges{

  @Input() dropdownItems: any[] = [];

  selectedItem: any;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes : SimpleChanges){
   if(changes.dropdownItems.currentValue != undefined){
     console.log(changes.dropdownItems.currentValue);
     this.dropdownItems = changes.dropdownItems.currentValue ; // your dropdownItems will have data passed y component
         console.log(this.dropdownItems);  <------- won't be Undefined
    this.selectedItem = this.dropdownItems[0];

    const dropdownButton = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.dropdown-button');
    dropdownButton.classList.remove('dropdown-button');
    dropdownButton.classList.add('dropdown-input-button');
   }
  }

  ngOnInit() {    
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have  distanceDropdownItems undefined in parent. Check out the link below showing an example to share the data using Input decorator to child.

[Share data from parent to child using Input decorator](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jrzihp)

If not, there could be another issue in the way the components are getting loaded in DOM, If child is placed in DOM before parent then `ngOnInit()` call happens only for the first time at the time of Init. And that would cause your input to be undefined in child. So You may try to implement  `ngOnChanges()` in place of `ngOnInit()`  which will help in picking up the value chnage from parent if there is a delay in parent loading and passing data to child.

Use `*ngIf` in your parent component to delay the initialization of the child component. You will bind the child component only if required object has a value.

Let me know if a code example would help and i can share here.